# Magento 2 Get Cart total in the controller / JS?

Tags: magento2, checkout

I am integrating the custom module of custom payment gateway. I need the **cart total** on the **checkout page** for the price conversion **before the payment**.

How can I get the Cart total in JS or in the custom controller? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');    
$totalItems = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsCount(); 
$totalQuantity = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsQty();
$grandTotal = $cart->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();
```

Hope it works for you..!!

Comment: with this code, no need to add object manager, because I already defined OM in above code.

Comment: Thanks, this function get the total. 

`$grandTotal = $cart->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();`